# Uploading Timestamp to a callable cloud function via its parameters gives _debugIsValidParameterType error in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try sending this object:

> I/flutter ( 2647): {profileJSON: {name: asdasd, bio: , bornDate: Timestamp(seconds=1184843149, nanoseconds=326366000)}}

like this:

```
await _firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable("updateUserProfile").call({
        "profileJSON": userProfileJSON,
      });
```

But I get this error back:

> 'package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart': Failed assertion: line 34 pos 12: '_debugIsValidParameterType(parameters)': is not true.

I tried removing the timestamp and it suddenly works. What do I need to do in order to send this timestamp to my cloud functions, so I can upload it from my cloud function to firestore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass your Timestamp as `Object` you need to pass it as `Long` or `Integer` value, and for generating Timestamp in Dart and converting it into Integer or Long value do it like this:

```
DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch
```

Comment: If I send this as a parameter to my cloud function, how will I then recreate the timestamp in the cloud function, using typescript, so that I can upload it to firestore from the cloud function?

Comment: It's too simple my friend just like this "var d = new Date(your_timestamp_number_here);", please mark this answer as the right one if this was helpful & I wish you the best 

Comment: If you have any further questions about this, please comment here

Comment: Hi!
I will mark it as answer later if nobody comments. I want to upload a firebase timestamp to firebase, that's my end goal, go from Flutter -> Cloud Function -> Firebase, but for some reason Flutter won't serialize the Timestamp. If there is no other solution, I will mark your answer as solution, as it's more of a work around instead of what I am really asking.

Comment: My friend it's not really just a workaround solution, every framework has its own object of Timestamp so you can't just send the entire object like that you have to pass it as a Long value and then create a Timestamp object based on this Long value that compatible with your framework implementation of Timestamp object.